# Can I make endless page with bootstrap 4 card-columns

Tags: bootstrap-4, pinterest, twitter-bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 comes with a new feature, called `card-columns` to make [masonry](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#columns)-like page. So I want to create an endless page with [pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/)-like behavior with bootstrap. But when the new element is inserted to the `card-column` it will be inserted to the left and not to the bottom.

So, is it possible to use it to create endless page?

Comment: Yes, [it's possible](http://www.codeply.com/go/KDgLEq6IGT). Post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of infinite/endless scrolling with [Bootstrap 4 card columns](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns) (masonry / pinterest).

http://codeply.com/go/KDgLEq6IGT

This example is done with Angular ([full article](https://uxplanet.org/angularjs-animated-placeholder-endless-scrolling-1b83c6bdd35a)), but basically it appends more `card`s inside the `card-columns` when the next "page" is loaded at the bottom.

EDIT: The order of the CSS columns is top to bottom, then left to right so the order of the rendered columns will be..

```
1  3  5
2  4  6
```

There is no way to change the order of CSS columns. It's suggested you use another solution like Masonry. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17882

Comment: The problem is that when cards are appended at the bottom in **card-column**, the page rerender and some cards in the top of the middle row move to the left and the left row to the middle.

Comment: In your example, too, all the new cards go to the rightmost column.